# keep the list-group open for desktop - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I keep the `list-group` open for `desktop(md)` device size. As of now it is functioning great as per tablet and mobile screen size. I want all the collapsed `div's` to be open for `desktop` screen size.

Here is a [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/D4oFGxEu0g)

Just to make it more clear:

```
/*Extra small devices Phones (<768px)*/
@media only screen and (min-width:768px){
   .......work as it is
}

/*Small devices Tablets (≥768px)*/  
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
    .......work as it is
}
/*Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)*/    
@media only screen and (max-width:992px){
    ....need the new behavior
}
```

Like this:

```
Expand
 Color
  Black
  White
 Size
  S
  M
 Fabric
  Cotton
  Lycra
```

here is the code I am working on

```
<div id="MainMenu" class="container">
    <div class="list-group panel">
        <a href="#demo3" style="color:black" class="list-group-item strong" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Expand<span class="plussign" style="color:#DC5034"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span></a>
        <div class="collapse in" id="demo3">
            <a href="#SubMenu6" class="list-group-item strong" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu6">Color<span class="plussign"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></a>
            <div class="collapse in list-group-submenu" id="SubMenu6">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Black</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">White</label>
                </div>

            </div>
            <a href="#SubMenu2" class="list-group-item strong" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu2">Size<span class="plussign"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></a>
            <div class="collapse in list-group-submenu" id="SubMenu2">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">S</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">M</label>
                </div>

            </div>
            <a href="#SubMenu3" class="list-group-item strong" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu3">Fabric<span class="plussign"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></a>
            <div class="collapse in list-group-submenu" id="SubMenu3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Cotton</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Lycra</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add an MVCE to your question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  If the link goes dead, your question becomes incomplete and unanswerable.

Comment: you mean, should i add some code here?

Comment: Yes, to the question here.  Also, can you try adding `.in` to `#demo3`?  As in:  `<div class="collapse in" id="demo3">`

Comment: `.in` works fine but it should work the way it was earlier for `tablet and mobile` devices.

Comment: and that would be how exactly?  Please remember I am not looking at what you are looking so I am not sure what your expected behaviour is and what the actual results are (and their difference).  Please read our [ask] to improve your question.  Great questions get great responses from the community

Comment: re-edited the question a bit, maybe it more clear now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `.in` to `#demo3`

As in: `<div class="collapse in" id="demo3">`

This will display the list expanded by default (but it can still be collapsed if needed)

**UPDATE**

Based on comments:

```js
// Wrap everything in an IIFE
$(window).resize(function() {
  // Executes in MD and LG breakpoints
  if ($(this).width() >= 992) {
    // expand collapsible toggle in demo3 (add other selectors as needed)
    $("#demo3").addClass('in');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="MainMenu" class="container">
  <div class="list-group panel">
    <a href="#demo3" style="color:black" class="list-group-item strong" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Expand<span class="plussign" style="color:#DC5034"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span></a>
    <div class="collapse" id="demo3">
      <a href="#SubMenu6" class="list-group-item strong" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu6">Color<span class="plussign"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></a>
      <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="SubMenu6">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Black</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">White</label>
        </div>

      </div>
      <a href="#SubMenu2" class="list-group-item strong" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu2">Size<span class="plussign"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></a>
      <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="SubMenu2">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">S</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">M</label>
        </div>

      </div>
      <a href="#SubMenu3" class="list-group-item strong" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu3">Fabric<span class="plussign"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></a>
      <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="SubMenu3">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Cotton</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Lycra</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: works fine, but it should be the same collapsed version for `mobile and tablet` sizes

Comment: I see, you may have to add that class in via JS (jquery) only when viewing on desktop